# Not allowed to load local resource on google chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html

i a php/jQuery script that list files from remote server. Files can be listed with all subfolders within but my problem is that when want to view file it does not open and through back error on browser console that Not allowed to load local resource: here are the scripts

scan.php

```
$files = array();



if(file_exists($dir)){

    foreach(scandir($dir) as $f) {
    
        if(!$f || $f[0] == '.') {
            continue; // Ignore hidden files
        }

        if(is_dir($dir . '/' . $f)) {

            // The path is a folder

            $files[] = array(
                "name" => $f,
                "type" => "folder",
                "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
                "items" => scan($dir . '/' . $f) // Recursively get the contents of the folder
            );
        }
        
        else {

            // It is a file

            $files[] = array(
                "name" => $f,
                "type" => "file",
                "path" => $dir . '/' . $f,
                "size" => filesize($dir . '/' . $f) // Gets the size of this file
            );
        }
    }

}

return $files;
```

php?>

script.js

```js
$(function(){

    var filemanager = $('.filemanager'),
        breadcrumbs = $('.breadcrumbs'),
        fileList = filemanager.find('.data');

    // Start by fetching the file data from scan.php with an AJAX request

    $.get('scan.php', function(data) {

        var response = [data],
            currentPath = '',
            breadcrumbsUrls = [];

        var folders = [],
            files = [];

        // This event listener monitors changes on the URL. We use it to
        // capture back/forward navigation in the browser.

        $(window).on('hashchange', function(){

            goto(window.location.hash);

            // We are triggering the event. This will execute 
            // this function on page load, so that we show the correct folder:

        }).trigger('hashchange');


        // Hiding and showing the search box

        filemanager.find('.search').click(function(){

            var search = $(this);

            search.find('span').hide();
            search.find('input[type=search]').show().focus();

        });


        // Listening for keyboard input on the search field.
        // We are using the "input" event which detects cut and paste
        // in addition to keyboard input.

        filemanager.find('input').on('input', function(e){

            folders = [];
            files = [];

            var value = this.value.trim();

            if(value.length) {

                filemanager.addClass('searching');

                // Update the hash on every key stroke
                window.location.hash = 'search=' + value.trim();

            }

            else {

                filemanager.removeClass('searching');
                window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(currentPath);

            }

        }).on('keyup', function(e){

            // Clicking 'ESC' button triggers focusout and cancels the search

            var search = $(this);

            if(e.keyCode == 27) {

                search.trigger('focusout');

            }

        }).focusout(function(e){

            // Cancel the search

            var search = $(this);

            if(!search.val().trim().length) {

                window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(currentPath);
                search.hide();
                search.parent().find('span').show();

            }

        });


        // Clicking on folders

        fileList.on('click', 'li.folders', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var nextDir = $(this).find('a.folders').attr('href');

            if(filemanager.hasClass('searching')) {

                // Building the breadcrumbs

                breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(nextDir);

                filemanager.removeClass('searching');
                filemanager.find('input[type=search]').val('').hide();
                filemanager.find('span').show();
            }
            else {
                breadcrumbsUrls.push(nextDir);
            }

            window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(nextDir);
            currentPath = nextDir;
        });


        // Clicking on breadcrumbs

        breadcrumbs.on('click', 'a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var index = breadcrumbs.find('a').index($(this)),
                nextDir = breadcrumbsUrls[index];

            breadcrumbsUrls.length = Number(index);

            window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(nextDir);

        });


        // Navigates to the given hash (path)

        function goto(hash) {

            hash = decodeURIComponent(hash).slice(1).split('=');

            if (hash.length) {
                var rendered = '';

                // if hash has search in it

                if (hash[0] === 'search') {

                    filemanager.addClass('searching');
                    rendered = searchData(response, hash[1].toLowerCase());

                    if (rendered.length) {
                        currentPath = hash[0];
                        render(rendered);
                    }
                    else {
                        render(rendered);
                    }

                }

                // if hash is some path

                else if (hash[0].trim().length) {

                    rendered = searchByPath(hash[0]);

                    if (rendered.length) {

                        currentPath = hash[0];
                        breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(hash[0]);
                        render(rendered);

                    }
                    else {
                        currentPath = hash[0];
                        breadcrumbsUrls = generateBreadcrumbs(hash[0]);
                        render(rendered);
                    }

                }

                // if there is no hash

                else {
                    currentPath = data.path;
                    breadcrumbsUrls.push(data.path);
                    render(searchByPath(data.path));
                }
            }
        }

        // Splits a file path and turns it into clickable breadcrumbs

        function generateBreadcrumbs(nextDir){
            var path = nextDir.split('/').slice(0);
            for(var i=1;i<path.length;i++){
                path[i] = path[i-1]+ '/' +path[i];
            }
            return path;
        }


        // Locates a file by path

        function searchByPath(dir) {
            var path = dir.split('/'),
                demo = response,
                flag = 0;

            for(var i=0;i<path.length;i++){
                for(var j=0;j<demo.length;j++){
                    if(demo[j].name === path[i]){
                        flag = 1;
                        demo = demo[j].items;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            demo = flag ? demo : [];
            return demo;
        }


        // Recursively search through the file tree

        function searchData(data, searchTerms) {

            data.forEach(function(d){
                if(d.type === 'folder') {

                    searchData(d.items,searchTerms);

                    if(d.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerms)) {
                        folders.push(d);
                    }
                }
                else if(d.type === 'file') {
                    if(d.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerms)) {
                        files.push(d);
                    }
                }
            });
            return {folders: folders, files: files};
        }


        // Render the HTML for the file manager

        function render(data) {

            var scannedFolders = [],
                scannedFiles = [];

            if(Array.isArray(data)) {

                data.forEach(function (d) {

                    if (d.type === 'folder') {
                        scannedFolders.push(d);
                    }
                    else if (d.type === 'file') {
                        scannedFiles.push(d);
                    }

                });

            }
            else if(typeof data === 'object') {

                scannedFolders = data.folders;
                scannedFiles = data.files;

            }


            // Empty the old result and make the new one

            fileList.empty().hide();

            if(!scannedFolders.length && !scannedFiles.length) {
                filemanager.find('.nothingfound').show();
            }
            else {
                filemanager.find('.nothingfound').hide();
            }

            if(scannedFolders.length) {

                scannedFolders.forEach(function(f) {

                    var itemsLength = f.items.length,
                        name = escapeHTML(f.name),
                        icon = '<span class="icon folder"></span>';

                    if(itemsLength) {
                        icon = '<span class="icon folder full"></span>';
                    }

                    if(itemsLength == 1) {
                        itemsLength += ' item';
                    }
                    else if(itemsLength > 1) {
                        itemsLength += ' items';
                    }
                    else {
                        itemsLength = 'Empty';
                    }

                    var folder = $('<li class="folders"><a href="'+ f.path +'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="folders">'+icon+'<span class="name">' + name + '</span> <span class="details">' + itemsLength + '</span></a></li>');
                    folder.appendTo(fileList);
                });

            }

            if(scannedFiles.length) {

                scannedFiles.forEach(function(f) {

                    var fileSize = bytesToSize(f.size),
                        name = escapeHTML(f.name),
                        fileType = name.split('.'),
                        icon = '<span class="icon file"></span>';

                    fileType = fileType[fileType.length-1];

                    icon = '<span class="icon file f-'+fileType+'">.'+fileType+'</span>';

                    var file = $('<li class="files"><a href="'+ f.path+'" title="'+ f.path +'" class="files">'+icon+'<span class="name">'+ name +'</span> <span class="details">'+fileSize+'</span></a></li>');
                    file.appendTo(fileList);
                });

            }


            // Generate the breadcrumbs

            var url = '';

            if(filemanager.hasClass('searching')){

                url = '<span>Search results: </span>';
                fileList.removeClass('animated');

            }
            else {

                fileList.addClass('animated');

                breadcrumbsUrls.forEach(function (u, i) {

                    var name = u.split('/');

                    if (i !== breadcrumbsUrls.length - 1) {
                        url += '<a href="'+u+'"><span class="folderName">' + name[name.length-1] + '</span></a> <span class="arrow">→</span> ';
                    }
                    else {
                        url += '<span class="folderName">' + name[name.length-1] + '</span>';
                    }

                });

            }

            breadcrumbs.text('').append(url);


            // Show the generated elements

            fileList.animate({'display':'inline-block'});

        }


        // This function escapes special html characters in names

        function escapeHTML(text) {
            return text.replace(/\&/g,'&amp;').replace(/\</g,'&lt;').replace(/\>/g,'&gt;');
        }


        // Convert file sizes from bytes to human readable units

        function bytesToSize(bytes) {
            var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
            if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
            var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
            return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        }

    });
});
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>file browser</title>


    <!-- Include our stylesheet -->
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
</br></br>
    <div class="container">
        <p align="center"><img src="img/vision.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" height="100" width="350"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="filemanager">

        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Find a file.." />
        </div>

        <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>

        <ul class="data"></ul>

        <div class="nothingfound">
            <div class="nofiles"></div>
            <span>No files here.</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!--<footer>
        
    </footer>-->

    <!-- Include our script files -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In addition if anyone can modify the code and add download button will be thankfull

Comment: Browser usually has no direct access to server filesystem. That's what it seems you want to do. I may be mistaken

Comment: Yes thats true, im trying access files from server. So what is best practice so i can accomplish this?